# Display different date format in Joomla

Tags: mysql, time, joomla, format

I created a query for my joomla site that takes a date from the mysql database and displays it

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('#__table.date');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__table'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('#__table.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$date = $db->loadResult();
echo $date;
```

The date is displayed in the format "Y, m, d" and I want it to be in the format "d, m, Y". I tried with:

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(date,'%d/%m/%Y') FROM `#__table.date` WHERE #__table.link_id=$link_id
```

But I do not know to write this code to work in joomla

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the date from the database. Afterwards you can transform it like this:

```
echo JHtml::date($date, JText::_('DATE_FORMAT_LC3'));
```

Date formats as localizable. You can use different keys to output the date:

```
DATE_FORMAT_LC="l, d. F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC1="l, d. F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC2="l, d. F Y H:i"
DATE_FORMAT_LC3="d. F Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC4="d.m.Y"
DATE_FORMAT_LC5="d.m.Y H:i"
DATE_FORMAT_LC6="d.m.Y H:i:s"
DATE_FORMAT_JS1="d.m.y"
DATE_FORMAT_CALENDAR_DATE="%d.%m.%Y"
DATE_FORMAT_CALENDAR_DATETIME="%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"
DATE_FORMAT_FILTER_DATE="d.m.Y"
DATE_FORMAT_FILTER_DATETIME="d.m.Y H:i:s"
```

Just use the one which fits you best.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not good in php. Mysql query from my post takes a date from the database and it is a $date variable. How do I insert the $date into your code?

Comment: What is the value of your $date variable and what is the output of the JHTML::date() function?

Answer (score 0):

Solved with following code (

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('#__table.date');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__table'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('#__table.link_id')." = ".$db->quote($link_id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$date = date_create($db->loadResult());
echo date_format($date,"d.m.Y");
```